# proofing if user exist in database or not - using pdo

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I want to check if a user (email) ist already in the database or not.

```
    $email_pruefen = ($_GET['email']);

    //SQL Statement ob email bereits existiert
    try {
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT rechnungsmail FROM kundendaten WHERE rechnungsmail = :checkmail");
            $stmt->execute([':checkmail' => $email_pruefen]);
            $fetchergebnis = $stmt->fetchAll(); //entnimmt alles aus dem Statement (Value, True/False, ..)

            if($fetchergebnis[0] > 0){
                $ergebnis = "Ja"; //Eintrag ist vorhanden
            } else {
                $ergebnis = "Nein"; //Eintrag ist nicht vorhanden
            }

            $pdo = null; //Verbindung schließen

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $meldung_checkemail = "Überprüfung der E-Mail Adresse war ohne Erfolg. Bitte wenden Sie sich an die IT.";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$meldung_checkemail');</script>";

        die();
    }


if($ergebnis == "Nein"){ //Wenn Email nicht existiert, führe folgendes aus
 ... create user ...
}else{
 ... dont create user ...
}
```

If there is no existing entry, the user can create it.

but my code dont work :I any ideas?

Comment: What part of the code does not work? We need specifics to be of any help

Comment: This looks dangerous `$pdo = null;` Assuming the part that does not work is the next bit where you create a new user?!!!

Comment: I can create the same email entry more than 1 time. but my IF($Ergebnis == "Nein") should be stop if the entry already exist

Comment: Then it might be useful to see the code `IF($Ergebnis == "Nein")` because currently WE CANNOT - Please remember we are not clairvoyant and cannot debug the code we cannot see

Comment: @KIKOSoftware and in this case I believed that a bit of a shout was warented

Comment: Won't this code `$fetchergebnis[0] > 0` returns an offset error if the query returned nothing? If so, then `$ergebnis = "Nein"` will never be reached

Comment: @CarlBinalla hm that could be the problem. Do you have any idea how I can proof it the right way?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I open it up later again. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your are comparing a **string** (email) with a **number** (0). In this case a string will be converted to a number and become **0**. 0 is not bigger than 0, so your condition returns `false`

Use just `$fetchergebnis` in your comparison and it would work. PHP is a loosely typed language, you can use a variable of almost any type in a conditional operator and any "non-empty" value wold work as `true`. A non-empty array as well.

Better yet, instead of `fetchAll()` which is unsuitable for this case, use a more appropriate `fetchColumn()` (but nevertheless check the direct result, the actual variable you get from fetch)

A canonical solution for your task: [How to check if email exists in the database?](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/check_email_exists)

Comment: You mean that I replace "$fetchergebnis[0] > 0" with "$fetchergebnis"? I tried it but I still can add new entrys with the same email.

Answer (score 1):

I tested `if($fetchergebnis[0] > 0)` using `var_dump()`, and it seems that this returns a `Undefined offset:0` plus `bool(false)`  when the statement fetched nothing *(tested it because I never tried using it before)*

One way is to use [`rowCount()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) before fetching to check if any row has been returned by the `SELECT` statement, something like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT rechnungsmail FROM kundendaten WHERE rechnungsmail = :checkmail");
$stmt->execute([':checkmail' => $email_pruefen]);

$ergebnis = ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) ? 'Ja' : 'Nein';
```

**OR**

Since you are just checking if something exist and not needing to use any data fetched from it, you can also use `COUNT(*)`:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kundendaten WHERE rechnungsmail = :checkmail");
$stmt->execute([':checkmail' => $email_pruefen]);
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
$ergebnis = ($count > 0) ? 'Ja' : 'Nein';
```

Comment: rowCount is not portable because not available across all drivers. Besides, it just makes no sense to select some data but not fetch it. count(*) is plausible but overkill. SELECT 1 would work as well

Comment: @YourCommonSense That's true, but this is just some alternatives, albeit not the best. Anyway, if it is okay with you, I'll add it as note in the answer

Comment: I checked both methods but it still dont worked for me. I could create new entrys with the same email.